# Pop Up with a listbox with a vertical scrollbar

Tags: python, tkinter

So i have the following problem:
I'm using grid and Toplevel for making a pop up window that has a vertical scrollbar the thing is that the scrollbar is appearing in the parent window(I already tried the in_ method an didn't work) so I was wondering what can I do?

```
class listbox:
    def __init__(self,master,tamx = 0,tamy = 0,h = 5,pop = True,line = 1,cul = 1,iden = True):

        self.iden = iden #verifies if a 
        self.master = master #window or widget I'm new here
        self.listb = Listbox(master,selectmode = 'browse',width = 15,height = ,font = ('arial','10')) 
        self.listb.grid(in_ = master,row = tamx,column = tamy,columnspan = columna,rowspan = fila) 
        self.pop = pop #to see if a pop up has to appear

        self.scroll = Scrollbar(command = self.listb.yview, orient= VERTICAL) #creates a scrollbar
        self.scroll.grid(in_ = master,row = tamx,column = tamy+1,sticky = 'ns') 
        self.listb.config(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
        if self.pop:
             self.listb.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.string) 

    def string(self,event):
        value = str((self.listb.get(self.listb.curselection())))
        popUp = pop(value,self.master,self.iden)    


class pop:
    def __init__(self,string,ventana,iden = True):
        if iden: #searching in a list of countries not really the point
        self.country = CodigoIntermedio._encontrar(paises,string) #searches the list for the specific country
        self.words = ['Code','Country','Capital','Surface','Gentilic'] #lists with the words for every characteristic form a country
        toplevel = Toplevel(master = ventana,bg = 'white')


        for x in range(len(self.palabras)): 
            label1 = Label(toplevel, text = self.words[x],bg = 'white') 
            label1.grid(in_ = toplevel,sticky = 'w',row = x)
            label2 = Label(toplevel, text=self.country[x],bg = 'white') 
            label2.grid(in_ = toplevel,sticky = 'w',row = x,column = 1)

            self.box = listbox(toplevel,tamx = 0,tamy = 2, pop = False,fila = 5,columna = 5)
            for x in range(len(self.country[5])): #searches for the words spoken in a country
                 value = CodigoIntermedio.encontrarCodigos(idiomas,self.country[5][x]) 
                 if valor:
                     self.box.listb.insert(END,valor) #los inserta en el listbox

         else: 
             self.language = CodigoIntermedio._encontrar(idiomas,string) 
             self.words = ['Code','Name','Speakers'] 
             toplevel = Toplevel(master = ventana,bg = 'white')


             for x in range(len(self.palabras)): 
                 label1 = Label(toplevel, text = self.words[x],bg = 'white')
                 label1.grid(sticky = 'w',row = x)
                 label2 = Label(toplevel, text=self.language[x],bg = 'white')
                 label2.grid(sticky = 'w',row = x,column = 1)

             self.box = listbox(toplevel,tamx = 0,tamy = 2, pop = False,fila = 3,columna = 3)
             for x in range(len(self.language[3])): 
             valor = CodigoIntermedio.encontrarCodigos(paises,self.idioma[3][x]) 
             if valor:
                 self.box.listb.insert(END,valor)
root = Tk()
root.configure(bg = 'white')
listCountries = listbox(root,tamx = 1, tamy = 0,h = 18)
#paises is a matrix with this structure:
#[[code of a country,name of the country,capital,total residents,gentilic,[list of codes of langauges]]
#CodigoIntermedio.encontrarCodigos searches for a country or a language in the matrix
#idiomas is a mtrix with this structure:
#[[code of the language,name,total speakers,[list of codes of the countries that speak it]]
#i get all the dat from a txt
for x in paises:
    listaCountries.listb.insert(END,x[1])
```

Comment: Mind Sharing some of your code?

Comment: The Scrollbar __is__ appearing? I do not see an issue with that. Please stick to the Information  user2314737  provided

Comment: The scroolbar has to appear in the listbox in the toplevel widget not in the parent

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the scrollbar's parent is the root window or some child of the root window. The scrollbar must have the parent be the toplevel, or some other widget that is in the toplevel.

Comment: Is it "windows" or "widgets" inside the toplevel?

Comment: @R4PH43L: everything is a widget. A "window" generally refers to the root widget, or instances of `Toplevel`. Another way to look at it is that windows float on the screen, widgets are embedded in them.

Comment: then it should be "or some other widget that is in the toplevel", no?

Comment: @R4PH43L: yes. Thank you.